# Rails PDF Prawn Headers and Footers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a simpler code to set the Headers and Footers on all N pages in a PDF file that is generated by PRAWN Plugin.

the codes are to be written in a

"**report.pdf.prawn**" file, which is a direct coding area of the PDF view page

The below are the codes in the file `report.pdf.prawn`

```
pdf.text "Creation Date " +  Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
pdf.text "Page Count:#{pdf.page_count}"
```

All i want is to position these values to headers or/and footers left and right side.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen the tips on this question? They may do what you're asking it sounds like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695019/header-and-footer-in-prawn-pdf

Answer (score 4):

Thank you so much for your concern.I got wat i want from the link
This is what i did to make it work..

```
creation_date = Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

page_count=pdf.page_count

powered_by = @companylogo 

# will get @companylogo from the controller

Prawn::Document.generate("show_sd_report_pdf.pdf", :skip_page_creation => true) do

pdf.page_count.times do |i|

pdf.go_to_page(i+1)

pdf.draw_text "Creation Date : " + creation_date, :at=>[590,530]

pdf.draw_text "Page Count : #{i+1} / #{pdf.page_count}", :at=>[1,1]

pdf.draw_text "Powered by : ", :at=>[590,1]

pdf.image powered_by, :width => 25, :at=>[670,15]

end

end

**or insted of draw_text**

pdf.bounding_box([1,540], :width => 300, :height => 300) do

pdf.text "Username : " + user_name

end
```